# How to remove the "Expand All" button from the Project View panel in PhpStorm

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2021.3.2 on Windows 10 and I want to remove the "Expand All" button from the Project View panel.

[image]

Comment: You cannot. There are no GUI options for that. Better say why do you want it to remove? because you miss-click a lot?

Comment: thanks, Yes I am Larval developer and when I mistakenly click on Expand all, all folders open completely such vendor and node-modules.

Comment: OK. But what icon do you want to click in the first place: the Collapse All or Select a File one? I'm thinking: maybe you can use keyboard shortcuts for that, which normally be faster and not cause such an issue...

Comment: Yes but this is the face cleansing of the problem.

Comment: a better workaround is to change your IDE icons

Comment: thanks @moghwan how can i do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can do it (I have the same problem too :D )

Step 1. Open the action and find "Registry"

[image]

Step 2. Find the key ide.project.view.expand.all.action.visible and turn it off

[image]

Step 3. Close the popup and you will see the result immediately

[image]

By "Expand all button", you're very anoying